# selecting records from parent / child tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have parent / child tables that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
  pnum varchar(10),
  dloc varchar(100),
  cc varchar(10),
  name varchar(255),
  group active bit(1)
);

CREATE TABLE group_members(
  id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
  group_id integer,
  member_id integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Users Data looks like:

```
ID  PNUM  DLOC          CC   NAME      GRP
 86|23101|dloc 89|    |          |0
 87|23101|dloc 90|    |          |0
 88|23102|dloc 91|    |          |0
590|12345|Group  |    |Test Group|1
591|90000|dloc 1 |    |          |0
```

group_members data looks like:

```
ID GROUP_ID   
1  |590    | 87
2  |590    | 88
```

Based on the PNUM, I would like to be able to get the dloc values for all users, whether its a group or not.

So for example, if someone requests pnum 23101, I would like to get back

- "dloc 89" and
- "dloc 90"

But if they request 12345, I would like to get back

- "dloc 90", and
- "dloc 91"

So far, I have come up with this query:

```
SELECT users.dloc 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id IN 
     (SELECT group_members.member_id
      FROM group_members 
      INNER JOIN users on users.id = group_members.group_id 
      WHERE users.pnum='12345');
```

That works for groups, but it won't return any results if i run the same query with pnum 23101.

**What I've tried so far**

I tried to see if I could use OR like so:

```
 SELECT users.dloc 
 FROM users 
 WHERE users.id in 
       (SELECT group_members.member_id 
        FROM group_members 
        INNER JOIN users on users.id = group_members.group_id 
        WHERE users.pnum='12345');
   OR
       (SELECT users.dloc 
        FROM users 
        WHERE pnum='12345')
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: _if someone requests pnum 23101, I would like to get back "dloc 89" and "dloc 90" But if they request 12345, I would like to get back "dloc 89", "dloc 90", and "dloc 99"_ Is that correct, or did you reverse it? The group (12345) has only 2 members while `pnum=23101` has 3 matching rows.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've updated the question.  Sorry, I did have some typos.  Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `UNION` to execute *both* queries, one of which matches directly on `PNUM` for values where `GROUP <> 1` and the other which matches on `PNUM` and joins through `group_members` for values where `GROUP = 1`.

In the second part, you need to join twice to `users` to get the members of the group matching the original `PNUM`.

Since the `GROUP` condition is opposite in each, only one part of the `UNION` will ever return results.

```
/* First part of UNION directly matches PNUM for GROUP = 0 */
SELECT dloc
FROM users
WHERE 
  PNUM = 23101
  AND `group` <> 1
UNION
/**
 Second part of UNION matches GROUP = 1
 and joins through group_members back to users
 to get member dloc (from the second users join)
 */
SELECT uu.dloc
FROM users u
   INNER JOIN group_members m ON u.`GROUP` = 1 AND u.id = m.group_id
   INNER JOIN users uu ON m.member_id = uu.id
WHERE 
   u.PNUM = 23101
```

This does unfortunately require placing the `PNUM` value twice in the query, once per `UNION` part, but that isn't so bad.

[Here it is in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51b9e7/5) (using MySQL rather than SQLite, but that doesn't really matter)

Using your original method with `OR` and an `IN()` subquery, it can also be done, but I've added `WHERE` conditions for `GROUP = 0` and `GROUP = 1`.

```
SELECT users.dloc 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id in (
    SELECT group_members.member_id 
    FROM group_members 
      INNER JOIN users on users.id = group_members.group_id 
    WHERE users.pnum='23101' AND `GROUP` = 1
 )
 OR users.id IN (
    SELECT users.ID
    FROM users 
    WHERE pnum='23101' AND `GROUP` = 0
);
```

[And here's the alternative method in action...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51b9e7/11)

Comment: @dot It can be done your original way as well, which I just added.

Comment: which way do you think is more efficient

Comment: @dot I didn't run `EXPLAIN` on them in MySQL (and SQLite would probably behave differently anyway) but if I had to guess I would bet they perform exactly the same way. They really are the exact same two queries, one is just packaged with a `UNION` and the other packaged as subqueries.  The `UNION` doesn't have an outer `IN()` condition to get the original users so it may be faster but I would doubt by much especially if `users.id` is indexed.

Comment: actually, i haven't indexed anything yet in this sqlite db because I wanted to find an article that discussed whether indexing for CRUD ops in sqlite really helps or not.

Comment: `id` is already a `PRIMARY KEY`, so that is indexed implicitly already. I forgot to consider that in my last comment.